# Re-locating a split system A/C to a different room

Tags: air-conditioning

I currently have a split system A/C unit in our living room that is really too small for the room. It runs full blast when it's turned on and whilst it does work at cooling the room, it's not efficient and never shuts off.

I would like to move this A/C unit into a bedroom (back-to-back installation), and buy a much larger unit for the living room.

I realise that due to the general nastiness to the environment of the refrigerant I will need to get a qualified person in to do this job, but is this something that's viable?

Will all the piping and wiring need replacing, or can they be re-used? If I have to replace all the piping and wiring, it's probably not going to be worth the expense as the living room is not a back-to-back installation (it has about 10m of piping to go from the living room to the compressor outside).

Comment: It's almost impossible to answer this with any certainty, from an internet away.  It depends on the condition of the pipe/wire, its compatibility with the new unit, among other things.

Comment: Just ask an AC contractor for a quote to do it both ways. That's your answer right there.